# What happens to RAII objects after a process forks?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, fork

Under Unix / Linux, what happens to my active RAII objects upon forking? Will there be double deletions?
What is with copy construction and -assignment? How to make sure nothing bad happens?

Comment: Why would you use fork, C++ is much better with Threads.

Comment: `fork(2)` is a fundamental Unix system call. You would use it ... every time you need a new process.

Comment: @OliverStutz: E.g. to create daemons or to run processes and capture their input-, output- and error-channel

Comment: @OliverStutz, to avoid all the problems (and thus many crashes) that threads come with. It's way more difficult to make sure your program works with threads than with a "simple" `fork()`, except maybe if you have RAII objects which manage external resources...

Comment: @AlexisWilke How do you can know that a complex program will work well with fork?

Comment: @curiousguy, by testing it? :-) Frankly, in comparison with threads, it's very easy to make a software work with `fork()`. You do not have all the memory problems and other shared resource issues you get with threads. The one thing not to do is have threads running when you `fork()`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Library code might use threads to do some operations in the background. If there is no user callback called from another thread, the library might not expose any thread to the user. The library only needs to protect its own shared resources.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`fork(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) creates a *full copy* of the process, including all of its memory. Yes, destructors of automatic objects will run twice - in the parent process and in the child process, *in separate virtual memory spaces*. Nothing "bad" happens (unless of course, you deduct money from an account in a destructor), you just need to be aware of the fact.

Comment: For memory only objects, or even objects holding a simple file descriptor, yes. Things are simple. Memory is duplicated with a copy-on-write and descriptors with a `dup()`. However, a destructor may do way more destructive things like do a `shutdown()` on a socket. That is NOT safe even across parent/child.

Comment: @AlexisWilke sockets are no different from any other file descriptor in *nix systems and it makes no sense to say that it is destructive when all non-special file descriptors are simply copied. Closest to what you claim that I can think of is child inheriting stdin/stdout/stderr, which is true, you have to redirect these if you don't want them interfering with parent, but even this is not even close to anything destructive, they simply take same input and provide same output through the same file descriptors.

Comment: @Sahsahae I was talking about the destructor calling `shutdown()` on your socket. You can always write a test: Open a socket in the parent, create a child (`fork()`), then do a shutdown in either one, the other's socket is dead. An unfortunate _feature_. Also, there is the `CLOEXE` flag which can be used to automatically close a descriptor on an `execve()`, for security reasons. However, if you just `fork()`, that won't matter.

Comment: @AlexisWilke indeed, you're correct. `shutdown` unlike `close` operates on the actual `socket` and not `sockfd`, something I overlooked, having never used this function before, as `close` already does "everything" you usually want. I can see how `shutdown` can be useful for multiprocess servers though, where a primary process is in control of most sensitive resources, like `sockets`, not `sockfd`s. Where it isn't necessary, a `close` is better choice for this exact reason. In hindsight, quite ironic how theory can catch up to reality like this.

Answer (score 5):

Principally, it is no problem to use these functions in C++, but you have to be aware of what data is shared and how.

Consider that upon `fork()`, the new process gets a complete copy of the parent's memory (using copy-on-write). Memory is *state*, therefore
you have two independent processes that must leave a clean state behind.

Now, as long as you stay within the bounds of the memory given to you, you should not have any problem at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo ()  { std::cout << "Foo():" << this << std::endl; }
    ~Foo()  { std::cout << "~Foo():" << this << std::endl; }

    Foo (Foo const &) {
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo():" << this << std::endl;
    }

    Foo& operator= (Foo const &) {
        std::cout << "Foo::operator=():" << this<< std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main () {
    Foo foo;
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // We are parent.
        int childExitStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, 0); // wait until child exits
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // We are the new process.
    } else {
        // fork() failed.
    }
}
```

Above program will print roughly:

```
Foo():0xbfb8b26f
~Foo():0xbfb8b26f
~Foo():0xbfb8b26f
```

No copy-construction or copy-assignment happens, the OS will make bitwise copies.
The addresses are the same because they are not physical addresses, but pointers into each process' virtual memory space.

It becomes more difficult when the two instances *share* information, e.g. an opened file that must be flushed and closed before exiting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    std::ofstream of ("meh");
    srand(clock());
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // We are parent.
        sleep(rand()%3);
        of << "parent" << std::endl;
        int childExitStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, 0); // wait until child exits
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // We are the new process.
        sleep(rand()%3);
        of << "child" << std::endl;
    } else {
        // fork() failed.
    }
}
```

This may print

```
parent
```

or

```
child
parent
```

or something else.

Problem being that the two instances do not enough to coordinate their access to the same file, and you don't know the implementation details of `std::ofstream`.

(Possible) solutions can be found under the terms "Interprocess Communication" or "IPC", the most nearby one would be `waitpid()`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main () {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        int childExitStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, 0); // wait until child exits
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        // fork() failed.
    }
}
```

The most simple solution would be to ensure that each process only uses its own virtual memory, and nothing else.

The other solution is a Linux specific one: *Ensure that the sub-process does no clean up*. The operating system will make a raw, non-RAII cleanup of all acquired memory and close all open files without flushing them. 
This can be useful if you are using `fork()` with `exec()` to run another process:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main () {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // We are parent.
        int childExitStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childExitStatus, 0);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // We are the new process.
        execlp("echo", "echo", "hello, exec", (char*)0);
        // only here if exec failed
    } else {
        // fork() failed.
    }
}
```

Another way to just exit without triggering any more destructors is the `exit()` function. I generally advice to not use in C++, but when forking, it has its place.

---

### References:

- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html
- man pages

Comment: I think your waitpid example would be better if it still showed the file being written to, but now in a predictable order. I'm not sure what the exec code is showing; was there supposed to be some other object that does or doesn't get cleaned up?

Comment: All you are showing here is a very simple synchronization problem. This can very easily be resolved with a lock (a mutex in a thread, because you would get similar problems in a thread... and probably a semaphore between the parent and in a forked child.) Either way has nothing to do with RAII per say. That is, **the point of RAII is the destructor of the class** and not using various things such as a file while the parent and the child are running.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Are you suggesting to keep a lock _around_ a resoure-full object, never mind how long the resource-full object is alive? Or, are you suggesting to make all resource-full classes threading-aware, just in case _someone_ may _somewhen_ use an instance in a threading context? I don't understand how this, as a general solution, is not premature pessimization.

Comment: If you want to write to a file in an orderly manner you need synchronization if more than one process has access to the file. In that specific case you can lock the file. That's what good log libraries do. You can have any number of processes sending logs simultaneously, and to get proper looking logs you (1) lock the file, (2) write your line of log, (3) unlock the file, and this is not specific to RAII.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: No, this is not specific to RAII. But ordering problems and doubled _effects_ (like accessing or modifying something a second time when this is not allowed) can follow from RAII, which is the point of the question ... Not sure what you are up to.

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer shows a **synchronization** problem which frankly has nothing to do with what problems RAII can really cause. That is, whether you use RAII or not, you will have **synchronization** problems between parent and child. Heck, if you run the same process in two different consoles, you have the exact same **synchronization** problem! *(i.e. no `fork()` involved in your program, just your program running twice in parallel.)*

To resolve **synchronization** problems, you may use a semaphore. See `sema_open(3)` and related functions. Note that a thread would generate the exact same synchronization problems. Only you can use a mutex to synchronize multiple threads and in most cases a mutex is much faster than a semaphore..

So where you do get a problem with RAII is when you use it to hold on what I call an external resource, although all external resources are not affected the same way. I have had the problem in two circumstances and I will show both here.

### Do not shutdown() a socket

Say you have your own socket class. In the destructor, you do a shutdown. After all, once you are done, you can as well send a message to the other end of the socket saying you are done with the connection:

```
class my_socket
{
public:
    my_socket(char * addr)
    {
        socket_ = socket(s)
        ...bind, connect...
    }

    ~my_socket()
    {
        if(_socket != -1)
        {
            shutdown(socket_, SHUT_RDWR);
            close(socket_);
        }
    }

private:
    int socket_ = -1;
};
```

When you use this RAII class, the `shutdown()` function affects the socket in the parent AND the child. That means both, the parent and the child cannot read nor write to that socket anymore. Here I suppose that the child does not use the socket at all (and thus I have absolutely no **synchronization** problems,) but when the child dies, the RAII class *wakes up* and the destructor gets called. At that point it shutdowns the socket which becomes unusable.

```
{
    my_socket soc("127.0.0.1:1234");

    // do something with soc in parent
    ...

    pid_t const pid(fork());
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        int status(0);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        // the fork() "duplicated" all memory (with copy-on-write for most)
        // and duplicated all descriptors (see dup(2)) which is why
        // calling 'close(s)' is perfectly safe in the child process.

        // child does some work
        ...

        // here 'soc' calls my_socket::~my_socket()
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // fork did not work
        ...
    }

    // here my_socket::~my_socket() was called in child and
    // the socket was shutdown -- therefore it cannot be used
    // anymore!

    // do more work in parent, but cannot use 'soc'
    // (which is probably not the wanted behavior!)
    ...
}
```

### Avoid using socket in parent and child

Another possibility, still with a socket (although you could have the same effect with a pipe or some other mechanism used to communicate externally,) is to end up sending a "BYE" command twice. This is actually very close to being a **synchronization** problem, though, but in this case, that *synchronization* happens in the RAII object when it gets destroyed.

Say for example that you create a socket and manage it in an object. Whenever the object gets destroyed, you want to tell the other side by sending a "BYE" command:

```
class communicator
{
public:
    communicator()
    {
        socket_ = socket();
        ...bind, connect...
    }

    ~communicator()
    {
        write(socket_, "BYE\n", 4);
        // shutdown(socket_); -- now we know not to do that!
        close(socket_);
    }

private
    int socket_ = -1;
};
```

In this case, the other end receives the "BYE" command and closes the connection. Now the parent cannot communicate using that socket since it got closed by the other end!

This is very similar to what phresnel talks about with his ofstream example. Only, it is not an easy to fix synchronization. The order in which you write the "BYE\n" or another command to the socket won't change the fact that in the end the socket gets closed from the other side (i.e. **synchronization** can be achieved using an inter-process lock, whereas, that `"BYE"` command is similar to the `shutdown()` command, it stops the communication in its track!)

## A Solution

For the `shutdown()` it was easy enough, we just do not call the function. That being said, maybe you still wanted to have the `shutdown()` happen in the parent, just not in the child.

There are several ways to fix the problem, one of them is to memorize the pid and use it to know whether these *destructive* function calls should be called or not. There is a possible fix:

```
class communicator
{
    communicator()
        : pid_(getpid())
    {
        socket_ = socket();
        ...bind, connect...
    }

    ~communicator()
    {
        if(socket_ != -1)
        {
            if(pid_ == getpid())
            {
                write(socket_, "BYE\n", 4);
                shutdown(socket_, SHUT_RDWR);
            }
            close(socket_);
        }
    }

 private:
     pid_t pid_;
     int   socket_;
 };
```

Here we do the `write()` and `shutdown()` only if we are in the parent.

Notice that the child can (and is expected to) do the `close()` on the socket descriptor since the `fork()` called `dup()` on all the descriptors so the child has a *different* file descriptor to each file it holds.

## Another Security Guard

Now there may be way more complicated cases where an RAII object is created way up in a parent and the child will call the destructor of that RAII object anyway. As mentioned by roemcke, calling `_exit()` is probably the safest thing to do (`exit()` works in most cases, but it can have unwanted side effects in the parent, at the same time, `exit()` may be required for the child to end cleanly--i.e. delete `tmpfile()` it created!). In other words, instead of using `return`, call `_exit()`.

```
pid_t r(fork());
if(r == 0)
{
    try
    {
        ...child do work here...
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // you probably want to log a message here...
    }
    _exit(0); // prevent stack unfolding and calls to atexit() functions
    /* NOT REACHED */
}
```

This is anyway much safer just because you probably do not want the child to return in the "parent's code" where many other things could happen. Not just stack unfolding. (i.e. continuing a `for()` loop that the child is not supposed to continue...)

The `_exit()` function does not return, so destructors of objects defined on the stack do not get called. The try/catch is **very important** here because the `_exit()` is not going to be called if the child raises an exception, although it should call the `terminate()` function which also won't destroy all the heap allocated objects, it calls the `terminate()` function after it unfolded the stack and thus probably called all your RAII destructors... and again not what you would expect.

The difference between `exit()` and `_exit()` is that the former calls you `atexit()` functions. You relatively rarely need to do that in the child or the parent. At least, I never had any strange side effect. However, some libraries do make use of the `atexit()` without consideration of the possibility a `fork()` gets called. One way to protect yourself in an `atexit()` function is to record the PID of the process which requires the `atexit()` function. If when the function gets called the PID doesn't match, then you just return and do nothing else.

```
pid_t cleanup_pid = -1;
void cleanup()
{
    if(cleanup_pid != getpid())
    {
        return;
    }

    ... do your clean up here ...
}

void some_function_requiring_cleanup()
{
    if(cleanup_pid != getpid())
    {
        cleanup_pid = getpid();
        atexit(cleanup);
    }
    ... do work requiring cleanup ...
}
```

Obviously, the number of libraries that use `atexit()` and do it right is probably very close to 0. So... you should avoid such libraries.

Remember that if you call `execve()` or `_exit()`, the cleanup will not occur. So in case of a `tmpfile()` call in the child + `_exit()`, that temporary file will not get deleted automatically...

Comment: The synchronization problem lies therein where destructors are guaranteed by C++ to execute, and there is no way around it, except wrapping instances as dynamically allocated objects. I don't really like to overengineer all my resource-full objects towards using non-standard functions, when the problem lies outside in application code that does not want to get their threading right. There are not only sockets that impose problems. It could also be a fancy HTML printing library, or a smart handle for a DirectPhysics wrapper on Windows.

Comment: I do answer the RAII question: "Will there be double deletions?" Which is also the title of the post. I mention the fact that all memory and descriptors get duplicated (second code sample,) which should be enough to know that everything will look the same in the child, at least at the start... As for objects allocated on the heap, they should make use of an `std::shared_ptr<>()`. That means they are guaranteed to be freed at some point. So the problem is to avoid the stack unfolding and `exit()` does that...

Comment: In essence, your answer is not really all too different from mine. Both of us just gave examples. And _both_ of us mention the use of exit() to cancel clean up. And, just as a side note: Not all heap objects belong into a `shared_ptr`. Copyable PIMPL classes for example should use a `unique_ptr` for their impl-pointer, in order to force its implementor to write proper copy-assignment and -construction.

Comment: @phresnel Ah! You do mention `exit()`! I missed it because it does not appear in your sample code... Yeah, allocated object should use some kind of smart pointer, some people prefer `unique_ptr<>()` for stack allocated objects too. Another thing I did not mention, [threads and `fork()` do not mix well](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) but that was not part of the question...

Comment: Calling `exit` in the child is incorrect and has caused bugs with severe security consequences. In general, you have no way to know what `atexit` handlers libraries might have registered and what they might do if invoked by the child and then again by the parent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, then maybe those libraries should not be used? One aspect of highly secure programming (say rockets for people or bombs) is to rewrite everything yourself so you have full control over each piece of code and you avoid problems such as the `atexit()`. However, most of the Unix software I know of will call `exit()` in the child process.

Comment: @AlexisWilke I think you're suggesting learning the wrong lesson. Sure, I agree, libraries like that shouldn't be used. But we only found that out by going through some very painful bugs with very serious security consequences. The lesson to learn is not to do things whose effects you can't know at the time you choose to do them, and calling `exit` in the child falls in that category. It's trivially avoidable. So why risk a repeat of past disasters?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the only safe way I can think of would be to do an `execve()`. But I don't yet see what you would propose...

Comment: @AlexisWilke The recommended way to terminate a child process is `_exit` if you're not going to call an `exec` function (or that function fails).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What about the cleanup the child needs? With `_exit()` you are not going to get the `tmpfile()` deleted when the child exits... Maybe a less problematic bug than a big security issue that `atexit()` can create. But overall, it's not really that much more of a solution.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Unfortunately, there are always going to be restrictions on what the child can do because you are inheriting an unknown context from libraries and the like. The child can't rely on exit handlers because it has no way to know what they're going to do. There are lots of ways around this, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: "`exit()` may be required for the child to end cleanly" Maybe. But many uses of `fork()` are for the end goal of calling an `execX` function anyway, so you may as well consider these system resources created under the hood by libraries will be lost most of the time because `atexit` "destructors" will not run.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know what you are doing, the child process should always call _exit() after it has done its stuff:

```
pid_t pid = fork()
if (pid == 0)
{
   do_some_stuff(); // Make sure this doesn't throw anything
   _exit(0);
}
```

The underscore is important. Do not call exit() in child process, it flushes stream buffers to disk (or wherever the filedescriptor is pointing), and you will end up with things written twice.

Comment: tho `man 2 _exit`: `[...] Whether it flushes standard I/O buffers and removes temporary files created with  tmp‐
       file(3)  is  implementation-dependent.[...]`

Comment: @phresnel, it's not just files. Actually closing file descriptors in the child is not a problem at all. Certain other problems, though, such as shutting down a socket have generally unwanted consequences.

Comment: Note that `Make sure it does not throw` could be changed with `try { do_some_stuff(); } catch(...) {} _exit(0);`. You may or may not catch things like SEGV, but it should still be pretty safe, generally speaking.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: SEGV is not an exception you can `catch` in C++. There are libraries that can produce that, though.